# How to properly have multiple threads access shared buffer

Tags: java, concurrency, deadlock, synchronizedcollection

I have a Producer/Consumer situation where producer produces domains for the consumer to visit. The Consumer sends a https request and grabs the links from the page and submits them back to the producer. When the Producer finishes, the consumer does not and hangs on the final domain. I cannot for the life of my figure out why this is happening.

> I have simplified my question

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        try
        {
            Broker broker = new Broker();

            ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);


            threadPool.execute(new Consumer(broker));
            threadPool.execute(new Consumer(broker));
            Future producerStatus = threadPool.submit(new Producer(broker));

            // this will wait for the producer to finish its execution.
            producerStatus.get();


            threadPool.shutdown();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Broker:

```
public class Broker {
    private BlockingQueue<String> QUEUE = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
    public Boolean continueProducing = Boolean.TRUE;

     public void put(String data) throws InterruptedException
     {
            this.QUEUE.put(data);
     }

     public String get() throws InterruptedException
     {
            //return this.queue.poll(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            return this.QUEUE.take();
     }
}
```

Consumer:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private Broker broker;


    public Consumer(Broker broker) {
        this.broker = broker;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {


        try {
            String data = broker.get();
            while (broker.continueProducing || data != null)
            {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Consumer " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " processed data from broker: " + data);
                data = broker.get();
            }

            System.out.println("Comsumer " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " finished its job; terminating.");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```

Producer:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable{

    private Broker broker;


    public Producer(Broker broker) {
        this.broker = broker;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
                System.out.println("Producer produced: " + "https://example" + i + ".com");
                Thread.sleep(100);
                broker.put("https://example" + i + ".com");
            }

            //broker.put("https://example.com/2");
            this.broker.continueProducing = Boolean.FALSE;
            System.out.println("Producer finished its job; terminating.");
        }catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated answer:

When I run your code, the consumer gets stuck on the line `data = broker.get()`. The broker is calling the `BlockingQueue.take` method. Here's the Javadoc for this method (emphasis mine):

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, *waiting if necessary until an element becomes available*.

That means that even if the producer isn't producing anything, the consumer will still wait for something to be produced.

One possible solution for you would be to use a "[poison pill](https://dzone.com/articles/producers-and-consumers-part-3)" approach. Assuming that you only ever have one producer, your `Broker` class could look like this:

```
public class Broker {

  private static final String POISON_PILL = "__POISON_PILL__";
  private BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

  public void put(String data) {
    queue.add(data);
  }

  public void doneProducing() {
    queue.add(POISON_PILL);
  }

  public String get() throws InterruptedException {
    String result = queue.take();
    if (result.equals(POISON_PILL)) {
      queue.add(POISON_PILL);
      return null;
    } else {
      return result;
    }
  }

}
```

---

Answer for previous code:

It would be great if you could narrow the scope of this question so that it included only the minimum amount of code to get the deadlock. As it currently is, there's a lot of code that you're posting that is not relevant, and there's some code that is relevant that you're not posting.

Additionally, there are a lot of problems with your current code. Your `toLinkedHashSet` method does not compile. In your add method, you're calling the `BlockingQueue.put` method even though your `BlockingQueue` should never hit its limit. You claim to want Ο(1) time for `contains`, but your code has Ο(n) time. You also seem to be doing a lot of unnecessary copying in your `addAll` and `contains` methods.

There's not enough information here for me to know what the problem is, but one thing that could be causing your problem is in your `get` method. If the consumer thread is interrupted, then your `get` method will cause it to uninterrupt itself (which probably wouldn't lead to a deadlock, but could look like one). In Java, it's very rarely acceptable to ignore an exception. If your call to the `take` method throws an `InterruptedException`, it's for a reason: another thread wants the current thread to stop. Your `get` method should throw `InterruptedException`. For example:

```
public String get() throws InterruptedException {
    return unprocessed.take();
}
```

If you really need the `get` method to not throw an `InterruptedException`, you could throw some other chained exception containing the `InterruptedException`. If it's really appropriate to return `""` on interruption, you could do something like this:

```
public String get() {
  try {
    return unprocessed.take();
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    return "";
  }
}
```

By interrupting the current thread, you are making sure that at least the current thread is marked as interrupted, so something down the line could deal with it. But throwing `InterruptedException` is probably most appropriate if possible.

I still don't understand why you're creating your own wrapper for `LinkedBlockingQueue`, as opposed to just using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` on its own. It seems like everything you're adding on top of `LinkedBlockingQueue` is doing nothing but slowing it down.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info. I am trying to make a spider that creates a single thread pool to add links to the queue until it reaches a max number of urls. While this is happening a specified number of reusable consumer threads grabs a  link from the queue and does some work. When that work is finished it submits a set of the results to the producer who will handle adding them to the queue so the reusable runnable can visit and process them. Throwing an an interrupt would make it so i would need to create the threads all over again correct?

Comment: If your call to `LinkedBlockingQueue.take` throws an `InterruptedException`, it means that another thread wants the current thread to stop. For example, a call to `Future.cancel(true)` or `ExecutorService.shutDownNow` would interrupt some threads. In other words, `InterruptedException` is how one thread communicates to another to stop whatever it's doing, and you're ignoring that message.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more details and more relevant code.

Comment: How would I go about not ignoring the message? I figured e.printStackTrace(); would show me the stacktrace of the exception, but that is not happening?

Comment: Looks like my issue may be with the  broker.get? Since it's blocking waiting for a new element to be added to the queue?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is the issue. See my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome thank! Quick question if I wanted to make the producer wait until more domains are provided how can I do this? With wait() and notify() ?

Comment: `wait` and `notify` are typically a bad idea because they're more primitive and harder to use. I'm not sure exactly what your use case requires, but the [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package has a lot of useful classes and interfaces, like `Phaser` and `CompletableFuture`. I'd recommend looking through those to see what fits your needs.

Comment: I have been reading about phasers. That looks like it will be what I need.